# How in the world does my server know my user is logged in without any auth_tokens?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise

I log into my Android app, and to test authentication, go to an activity which requires a user to be logged in, but I purposely don't pass along my authentication token, yet still receive the data from devise as if I was signed in. I've tested this for multiple users, and am extremely perplexed. I'm new to Devise so perhaps I don't know exactly how it works? How is my server supposed to know which user I am if I don't pass the authentication token?

Comment: Have they logged in already, and are they being kept logged in via a cookie/session?

Comment: The only way I've established one being logged in is via the `auth_token`. If that isn't being passed around, then the user isn't logged in.

Comment: The auth token doesn't need to be passed around, though, if that user has a cookie in their client which effectively tells your server to keep them logged in.

Comment: I do store the `auth_token` in a `SharedPreferences` object, which keeps the token under `User`. I don't expect it to be this easy though communicating my Android App w/ Rails backend.

Comment: Even when I don't store the token, as I just tried, it seems to know I'm logged in.

Comment: Add this to your controller action to see exactly what is sent through from the client.  `    puts "headers: \n#{request.headers.collect{|k,v| "#{k.inspect} => #{v.inspect}"}.join("\n")}"`

Comment: The only things that stand out to me are the `_Card_api_session` and `action_dispatch.secret_token`.

Comment: `_Card_api_session` probably means you have a cookie and you pass it to Rails. What is the content of this header?

Comment: It's a long-winded string much like "GWAGO214MAOGMWVAA14TAAVOPM" though much longer.